# Multiple right if-conditions Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

pretty simple question, hard solution, at least for me.
How I can do the code of an if and else if statement when the conditions are both time right?
like I do a variable x and y and I check if x is 5 then it says something but it says something else when y is 5 either, now the point is what if both are 5? bc after one if statement it skips the other if/else if.
thanks for ur solutions!

Comment: `if a && b { } else if a &&!b { } else if !a && b { } else {  //it's !a && !b case }`?

Comment: well the point is, my if statement is longer than just simple x and y and if I do that with every condition, I need about 15 lines for just one out of five ifs :)

Comment: You can't use `if ... else if ... ` in that case, because once one condition is met, no further evaluations will be done. Why not just do ,`if x == 5 { ...} if y == 5 { ...}`

Comment: That's actually working, I tried that before and I got an error, seems like my code was just not working before *sometimes dumb* thanks a lot tho!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift actually has a very powerful switch statement that you can use to check the value of multiple variables. Consider this code:

```
var x: Int = 3
var y: Int = 5

switch (x, y) {
case (1, 4):
    print("x == 1 and y == 4")
case (3, 5):
    print("x == 3 and y == 5")
case (5, 5):
    print("x and y are both 5")
case (5, let y) where y > 5:
    print("x == 5. Y > 5")
case (5, _):
    print("x == 5. y == some value we didn't test for.")
case (_, 5):
    print("y == 5. x == some value we didn't test for.")
default:
    print("Dunno")
}
```

It works by combining multiple values into a tuple, and then switching on the tuple. The cases inside the switch statement can do all kinds of different tests on the values of the tuple.

That code prints:

> x == 3 and y == 5

With the values I assigned to it. The "_" bit means "don't care" for that part of the tuple. The "let y" means "Take the second value in the switch statement and assign it to a local variable y that only exists in this case." You can then add a "where" clause that lets you do more complex tests, like my "where y > 5" example.

### Edit:

As Jessy pointed out in their comment, binding a value to y with `let y` in my `case (5, let y) where y > 5:` example is pointless, since the switch statement is already operating on a variable named y. It would work just as well as `case (5, _) where y > 5:` in that particular example.

However, if the switch statement was a switch on constant values (e.g. `switch (x, 7)`) or on a tuple variable:

```
let aTuple = (5,7)
switch aTuple {
   case (5, let y) where y > 5:
...
```

Then binding the second value to a variable **would** be useful.

Comment: It’s a great answer but there’s not a point in rebinding the same thing to the same name.

Comment: Just wondering if `var x: Int = 3` should be added for completeness so that it is clear why the output is `x ==3 and y == 5`

Comment: Great answer, but as I understandit, OP was just mentally stuck with an `if .. else if ...` with independent conditions where he needed both branches to execute. Ie, no need for the `else if` at all, just two distinct `if x == 5` and `if y== 5`

Comment: @ShawnFrank, I guess I didn't select that part of my sample code before copying it. I've added it back. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @DuncanC - forgot to mention before, great answer and good eye opener to showing how powerful Swift's switch can be

Comment: @Jessy, fair point on rebinding. I wanted to illustrate the technique of binding to a local var and using where, but my example wasn't ideal for that.